# Create DataView using DataTable's rows properties

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `DataTable` which is bound to `DataGridView`. `DataTable` has several columns which have FK and/or unique constraints defined. After loading data into `DataTable` some rows have property **HasErrors** set to *true*. I'm looking for a way to show in `DataGridView` all `DataTable` rows or only rows with errors, while giving user ability to edit rows of `DataTable` in each view mode.
I tried

```
DataGridView testDGV;
DataTable testDT;
testDGV.DataSource = testDT.Select().Where(row => row.HasErrors == true).CopyToDataTable();
```

but this creates different `DataTable`.
Is it possible to create `DataView` using rows properties in filter criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
testDGV.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.HasErrors == true).AsDataView();
```

This should create a `DataView` over the filtered `DataTable`, so basically your not creating a new `DataTable` but it's the same, just wrapped up.